# Cannot dockerize Prisma node mysql application @prisma/client did not initialize yet

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, docker-compose, prisma

I am having lots of trouble resolving this bug. I wrote a prisma nodejs application with react frontend and am ready to deploy. The app is working perfectly on my ubuntu system but everytime i try to run

sudo docker-compose up --build
I run into the same error

```
app/node_modules/.prisma/client/index.js:3
    throw new Error(
    ^

Error: @prisma/client did not initialize yet. Please run "prisma generate" and try to import it again.
In case this error is unexpected for you, please report it in https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues
    at new PrismaClient (/app/node_modules/.prisma/client/index.js:3:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/build/decks.js:10:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1209:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:868:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1057:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/build/game.js:41:17)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:14)
/app/node_modules/.prisma/client/index.js:3
    throw new Error(
```

no matter what i try

this is my Dockerfile for my node application:

```
FROM node:16

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./
COPY prisma ./prisma/

COPY . .

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 8000

CMD [ "node", "build/server.js" ]
```

my .env

```
MYSQL_HOST="localhost"
MYSQL_USER="game" 
MYSQL_NAME="mygame"
MYSQL_PASS="mypassword" 
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mynewpassword
DB_URL="mysql://game:mypassword@localhost:3307/mygame" 
DB_LOCAL_PORT=3307 
DB_DOCKER_PORT=3308 
NODE_LOCAL_PORT=8000 
NODE_DOCKER_PORT=8000
```

and my package.json

```
{
  "name": "nodejsin30min",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./src/server.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "generate": "npx prisma generate",
    "deploy": "npx prisma migrate deploy",
    "devStart": "nodemon ./src/server.ts",
    "test": "jest",
    "build": "tsc -p",
    "postinstall": "prisma generate"
  },
  "prisma": {
    "schema": "./prisma/schema.prisma"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@prisma/client": "^4.6.1",
    "@socket.io/admin-ui": "^0.2.0",
    "@types/jest": "^28.1.7",
    "@types/mocha": "^9.1.1",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
    "bcrypt-helper": "^0.2.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.1",
    "chroma": "^0.0.1",
    "circular-json": "^0.5.9",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-jwt": "^7.7.7",
    "express-oauth2-jwt-bearer": "^1.2.0",
    "express-openid-connect": "^2.9.0",
    "express-rate-limit": "^6.7.0",
    "flatted": "^3.2.5",
    "jwks-rsa": "^2.1.5",
    "knex": "^2.3.0",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "mysql2": "^2.3.3",
    "prisma": "^4.6.1",
    "socket.io": "^4.4.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.4.0",
    "sqlite3": "^5.0.9",
    "typesync": "^0.9.2",
    "underscore": "^1.13.1",
    "webpack": "^5.74.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@prisma/client": "^4.6.1",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/express-jwt": "^7.4.2",
    "@types/jest": "^28.1.7",
    "@types/mocha": "^9.1.1",
    "@types/mysql": "^2.15.21",
    "@types/node": "^18.7.7",
    "@types/underscore": "^1.11.4",
    "jest": "^27.4.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
    "prisma": "^4.6.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^4.4.3"
  }
}
```

As you can see I already tried implementing a posinstall script with no luck. I have already tried shifting around multiple prisma commands (migrate dev, migrate deploy, generate) into every possible position of my Dockerfile with no luck - always the same error. On my device I NEVER had to manually generate a client and before i implemented prisma the application could be built just fine. I have no more ideas what to look for.

any help is appreciated.

Furthermore i habe already tried leaving out enironment variables and instead hardcoding the values, which did not work either

I also tried running RUN npm i -g prisma befor a prisma generate in my Dockerfile

Comment: _`MYSQL_HOST="localhost"`_  this seems to be a problem. Where is MySQL running? In another container managed by Docker Compose? Use the service name. Locally on your host computer? Use `host.docker.internal`. The same would apply to your `DB_URL` variable